# UI is not updating after receiving a message

Tags: javascript, angular, sockets, websocket, reactive-programming

I receive a message, I log it in console which is logged correctly, I push the data in the array but the UI is not updating.

```
  constructor(
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {

  ngOnInit(): void { 
    socket.on('connect', () => {

     socket.on('recieveMessage', (msg) => {
       console.log('recievemessage is triggered')
        this.messagesArr.push(msg);
        this.cdr.markForCheck();
     })

    }) 
  }
```

Then I tried to remove the socket.on('connect'), but then It's logged in the console more than one time, but the UI is updating successfully, the message is added properly on the UI, once.

The code:

```
  constructor(
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {

  ngOnInit(): void { 
     socket.on('recieveMessage', (msg) => {
       console.log('recievemessage is triggered')
        this.messagesArr.push(msg);
        this.cdr.markForCheck();
     })
  }
```

Can someone help me? (I also used this.cdr.detectChanges() in both examples)

Comment: can you show the html file, what you're expecting to change in UI.

Comment: Did you change the [ChangeDetectionStrategy](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy)?

Comment: My solution works?

Answer (score 1):

Define a new array for message call him for example messages and use it in the view:

```
messages: any[] = [];
messagesArr: any[] = [];

ngOnInit(): void { 
     socket.on('recieveMessage', (msg) => {
       console.log('recievemessage is triggered')
        this.messages = this.messagesArr.push(msg);
        this.cdr.markForCheck();
     })
  }
```

In html

```
<div *ngFor="let message of messages">.......
```

Comment: That's an idea but I will have two arrays where I store the same information, but I will try it, thanks